# ¿ Como debo cambiar el tamaño de las letras a un span?

Tags: css, wordpress, style, font-size

Quiero cambiar el tamaño por defecto de esta sección de un sitio WordPress, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.
Debo decir que únicamente he probado el siguiente código:

```
.widget-title  shop-sidebar {
        font-size: 22px;
}
```

También he utilizado `!important` , sin que haga cambios en el tamaño de las letras

```
.widget-title  shop-sidebar {
        font-size: 22px !important;
}
```

Esta es la parte donde quiero hacer los cambios:

```
<span class="widget-title  shop-sidebar"> Categorias </span>
```

¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: en la parte de tu css shop-sidebar deberia de tener un . antes de la palabra, puesto que es una clase no una etiqueta, tambien deberia de estar pegado a .widget-title ya que se encuentran en la misma etiqueta html

Comment: Pues en WordPress, cuando veo los elementos con el inspector de Google, se muestra separado. https://ibb.co/SxTrWxL.

Comment: claro porque en el atributo class la cada clase se separa por espacios, pero para usarlas como selector, estando en el mismo atributo es pegado .widget-title.shop-sidebar{ }

Comment: lo que dice @StialManstike es correcto, la sintaxis que usas esta mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo el código que muestras  ( `<span class="widget-title  shop-sidebar"> Categorias </span>` ), quizá es porque no has añadido la etiqueta `span` .
Prueba de la siguiente manera, eso debe funcionar

```
span.widget-title  shop-sidebar {
        font-size: 22px;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo porque esta respuesta fue aceptada, la sintaxis es incorrecta, lo correcto sería span.widget-title.shop-sidebar por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Thank you dear @JefferzonBol . I must use the options of the two answers, and the code of the answer that I accept as good works. Personally, the little knowledge of css that I have, I know that I should use `!important` as little as possible. I don't know what you think about this syntax error, it works perfectly for me without using `!important`, and I must say that `shop-sidebar` is unnecessary, but it still works. And thanks to this answer I got what I needed, even if you don't like it. But it works perfectly, adding `shop-sidebar` and without adding `shop-sidebar`.

Answer (score 1):

lE `.shop-sidebar` debes llamarlo como una clase, junto con las anteriores clases y etiquetas para entrar a la clase correctamente, podrías hacerlo así:

```
.widget-title, .shop-sidebar { 
   font-size: 22px !important;
 }
```

O también llamando a la etiqueta span:

```
span .widget-title .shop-sidebar { 
   font-size: 22px !important;
 }
```